# нет декларации «fcvt» в этой области видимости

Tags: c, gcc

Имеется код:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/signal.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<sys/resource.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Employee {
    char name[35];
    char number[10];
    char income[10];
    char tax[4];
} em[5];

// процедура для обслуживания соединения
int Func(int newS) {
    long int i, num, t, mon, doh, nal;
    float sum;
    int m;
    char p, p1, s;
    char buf[256], b[256];
    while (true) {
        recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        p = buf[0];
        switch (p) {
        case '1':
            buf[0] = '\0';
            sum = 0;
            recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
            mon = atoi(buf);
            recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

            s = buf[0];
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                if (em[i].name[0] == s) {
                    nal = atoi(em[i].tax);
                    doh = atoi(em[i].income);
                    printf("mon %d\n", mon);
                    sum = sum + (nal*doh*mon) / 100.0;
                }
            int *decpt, *sgn;
            printf("%f\n", sum);
            strcpy(buf, fcvt(sum, 3, decpt, sgn));
            send(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
            puts(buf);
            break;
        case '2':
            recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);  //Номер
            num = atoi(buf);
            printf("%d\n", num);

            recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
            p1 = buf[0];
            switch (p1) {
            case '1':
                recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0); //Имя
                strcpy(em[num].name, buf);
                break;
            case    '2': recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0); //Таб.номер
                strcpy(em[num].number, buf);
                break;
            case '3':recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0); //Доход
                strcpy(em[num].income, buf);
                break;
            case '4': recv(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0); //Ставка налога
                strcpy(em[num].tax, buf);
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                buf[0] = '\0';
                strcat(buf, em[i].name); strcat(buf, " ");
                strcat(buf, em[i].number); strcat(buf, " ");
                strcat(buf, em[i].income); strcat(buf, " ");
                strcat(buf, em[i].tax); strcat(buf, "\n");
                send(newS, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            exit(0);

        }
    }
}
void reaper(int sig) {
    int status;
    while (wait3(&status, WNOHANG, (struct rusage*)0) >= 0);
}

int main() {
    strcpy(em[1].name, "Sergeev Sergei Sergeevich");
    strcpy(em[1].number, "1");
    strcpy(em[1].income, "100000");
    strcpy(em[1].tax, "10");

    strcpy(em[2].name, "Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich");
    strcpy(em[2].number, "2");
    strcpy(em[2].income, "200000");
    strcpy(em[2].tax, "20");

    strcpy(em[3].name, "Vladimirov Vladimir Vladmirvich");
    strcpy(em[3].number, "3");
    strcpy(em[3].income, "300000");
    strcpy(em[3].tax, "30");

    strcpy(em[4].name, "Sidorov Sidor Sidorovich ");
    strcpy(em[4].number, "4");
    strcpy(em[4].income, "400000");
    strcpy(em[4].tax, "40");

    strcpy(em[5].name, "Vasilev Vasilii Vasilievich");
    strcpy(em[5].number, "5");
    strcpy(em[5].income, "500000");
    strcpy(em[5].tax, "50");

    struct sockaddr_in local;
    int s, newS, rc;

    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(7500);
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    rc = bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, sizeof(local));
    rc = listen(s, 5);
    (void)signal(SIGCHLD, reaper);
    while (true) {
        newS = accept(s, NULL, NULL);
        switch (fork()) {
        case 0:
            (void)close(s);
            exit(Func(newS));
        default:
            (void)close(newS);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции выдает следующую ошибку:

```
server.cpp: В функции «int Func(int)»:
server.cpp:47:16: ошибка: нет декларации «fcvt» в этой области видимости
    strcpy(buf, fcvt(sum, 3, decpt, sgn));
```

В чем проблема? Вроде необходимый заголовочный файл подключен

Comment: Какая версия ОС и компилятора?  (У меня `uname -a
Linux avp-ubu1 4.4.0-137-generic #163-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 24 13:14:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` и `gcc.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609` `fcvt()` работает. Кстати, передаваемые в нее указатели надо инициализировать правильными адресами)

Comment: @avp, я cygwin пользуюсь, поэтому вот: CYGWIN_NT-10.0 DESKTOP-BVQA2FM 2.11.1(0.329/5/3) 2018-09-05 10:24 x86_64 Cygwin

Comment: Про винду не знаю, но можете попробовать использовать `sprintf(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас в системе не реализована `fcvt()`, то 
навскидку (без более-менее обстоятельной отладки) ее код может выглядеть так:

```
char *
fcvt(float v, int prec, int *point, int *sign)
{
  static char buf[32];
  char fmt[8],
    *r = buf;

  sprintf(fmt, "%%.%df", prec);
  sprintf(buf, fmt, v);
  *sign = 0;
  if (buf[0] == '-')
    *sign = 1, ++r;
  char *p = strchr(r, '.');
  if (p) {
    *point = p - r;
    for (int i = 1; p[i - 1] = p[i]; i++);
  } else
    *point = 0;

  return r;
}
```